# jQuery show DIV and scroll to it without hashtag in url

Tags: jquery, hash

I have the following simple jQuery:

```
            $('#features').hide();

            $('#more').click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#more').hide();
                $('#features').show();
            });
```

This shows a DIV when a user clicks the more link and using the preventDefault method the `#features` hash isn't added to the url. However I still want to scroll down to that DIV in the same way as when a hash is passed to the url just not show it in the address bar. How do I do this? Thanks

**Note: I'm not looking for any fancy effects etc so don't want to use plugins like scrollTo etc**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use [`$(window).scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
$('#more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#more').hide();
    $('#features').show();
    $(window).scrollTop($('#features').offset().top);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($("div#features").offset().top);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/4XEVc/